# iOS Retain or Reuse Child ViewControllers

Tags: ios, memory-management, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I try to use Container ViewController features.
I initiate several ViewControllers from Storyboard with Storyboard identifiers.
And keep those instances for switching between them and reuse them.

But somehow the references are deallocated randomly.
Is it able to keep their references and reuse them?

Comment: Is this the same question you just asked?

Comment: No, It's different. I think it is forced to release when the memory is low. But the subview also holding reference in a mutable array is ARC issues.

Comment: Show how you are loading, using and storing the view controllers.

Comment: I just simply keep the reference as a class member. Somehow it is deallocated by system when memory is low I guess. So I can not access its view. I read some article said that its view is lazy init.